# Помогите найти логическую ошибку

Tags: python

````
```
import json


def get_stored_username():
    """Получает хранимое имя пользователя, если оно существует."""
    filename = 'username.json'
    try:
        with open(filename) as f_obj:
            username = json.load(f_obj)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return username


def check_user():
    """Проверяет имя пользователя"""
    answer = input(f"Is your name {get_stored_username().title()}? \nYes/No ")
    if answer.lower() == 'yes':
        return True
    elif answer.lower() == 'no':
        return False
    else:
        print("Enter only 'Yes' or 'No'.")
        check_user()


def get_new_username():
    """Запрашивает новое имя пользователя"""
    username = input("What is your name? ")
    filename = 'username.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(username, f_obj)
    return username


def greet_user():
    """Приветствует пользователя по имени"""
    username = get_stored_username()
    if username and check_user():
        print(f"Welcome back, {username.title()}!")
    else:
        username = get_new_username()
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username.title()}!")


greet_user()
```
````

Программа при первом запуске запрашивает имя и сохраняет его в файл. При повторном запуске она переспрашивает пользователя он ли это. Если он отвечает да, то приветствует его по имени, если нет, то запрашивает его имя.
Где-то допустил логическую ошибку и никак не могу ее найти.
Суть в том, что если в файле уже есть имя и на вопрос "Ваше имя Х?" сначала ответить не "Да" или "Нет", а ввести любое другое невалидное значение, а когда она еще раз переспросит этот же вопрос, то со второго раза ответить на него "Да", то программа не будет приветствовать как должна, а запросит у пользователя новое имя.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться где ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте return перед check_user():

```
print("Enter only 'Yes' or 'No'.")
return check_user()
```

Но лучше вообще убрать рекурсивный вызов check_user(), обернув при этом весь блок запроса имени и проверок (т.е. всё тело функции) в "вечный" цикл `while True:`

Comment: Благодарю вас! Оба способа действительно работают и выдают ожидаемый результат.
Но могли бы вы объяснить в чем именно была ошибка, чтобы я в будущем ее не повторял?
Почему мой код не работал как нужно, а с вашими правками все работает?

Comment: Если вы не делаете return, то функция по окончании ничего не возвращает. Питон в этом случае считает, что функция вернула None. А None при проверке через if равносилен False. Получалось как будто ваша функция в этом случае возвращает False независимо от того, что ввёл пользователь.

Comment: И почитайте про рекурсию, возможно вы не до конца понимаете, как она работает. При рекурсивном вызове return вернёт управление в место последнего вызова, и если это было то место в этой же функции, где не было return, а был просто вызов этой же функции, то и получится, что функция в итоге ничего не вернула, хотя где-то в глубине рекурсии и был вызван return. Но дальше по цепочке возвращенный и результат уже не передался, потому что там уже не было return этого результата.

Comment: Хочу еще раз вас поблагодарить за помощь и отдельно за объяснения. Я перечитал их много раз, нагуглил дополнительную информацию и наконец-то разобрался с вопросом и понял как это работает.
Способ через "вечный" цикл while True действительно лучше. Если бы я знал, что return внутри цикла в функции прерывает цикл, то вероятно воспользовался бы им. Даже приходила в голову эта мысль, но боялся, что цикл действительно будет вечным и не стал даже пробовать. PyCharm ругался на break после return, а я не знал, что в цикле внутри функции они оба прерывают цикл.
Теперь благодаря вам я знаю больше!

Comment: @serg_new_user Хорошо, что разобрались :)  На всякий случай ещё уточню, почему рекурсия - это плохо и её нужно избегать. Как минимум это нужно делать из-за того, что глубина рекурсии в Python довольно сильно ограничена по сравнению с другими языками и при определённой глубине рекурсии интерпретатор просто "упадёт". Можно, конечно, заранее посчитать, способен ли ваш код достичь такой глубины рекурсии, но гораздо проще её никогда не использовать. Ну, может быть кроме учебных целей, чтобы знать, что это такое и как она реализуется.